# Live updater chat script

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

So I'm kind of new to php, and I'm trying to write a php live chat web application... It stores the chat data in a mysql database. Then I call the UpdateDb() function I typed out below every couple seconds to refresh the chat content it shows in the div I have the php code in.(the chat data is echoed from the mysql table in that div)... But every time it calls the UpdateDb() function, if you have the text input that you type the message into focused(selected), it blurs it and you can never type a message in, because it keeps deselecting it. :( ... Does anyone have any better codes to update the content that's in a certain div? I would really appreciate any help anyone could give... (Keep in mind, I'm not a pro in php, and I don't know much about javascript). If I need to post the whole document code, I can, if you don't know what I mean... I would actually like to do the whole thing in php if I can, but I don't know if there's a way to.

```
function UpdateDb()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest){           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();}else{     // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()  
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("messages").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}

xmlhttp.open("GET","chat2.php",true);xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take two approaches here:

1) You do Ajax request to server to get only JSON output of messages, newer than some `message_date`. Than you create HTML wrapper for that JSON data and append to messages list (sorry, i use jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
   url: 'ajax/getMessages',
   type: 'post',
   data: {last: $("#lastMessageDate").val()},
   success: function (newMessages) { // newMessages contains JSON of messages
      $.each(newMessages, function(key, message){
         $("#messages").append("<div class='message'>" + message.content + "</div>");
      }); 
   }
});

<div id="messages">
   <div class="message">
       <?php echo $message['content']; ?>
   </div>
   <input type="hidden" value="2014-10-20 12:52" id="lastMessageDate"/>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```

2) Use same view, just reload single element. (Again jQuery)

```
$("#messages").load(window.location.href + " #messages > *");

<div class="messages">
   <?php foreach ($dbMessages as $message) { ?>
       <div class="message"><?php echo $message['content']; ?></div>
   <?php } ?>
</div>
<textarea></textarea>
```